# Firemonkey LiveBinding to TListbox to show images

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I'm trying to use LiveBindings with `TListbox`.  This works with `TListview` but not `TListbox`.  I'm trying to display only images in a `TListbox` (no text) but added CustomerID just to show the LiveBindings works.  Just that the image does not display from the CustomerPhoto blob field.

```
LinkFillControlToField1.Control := Listbox1;
with LinkFillControlToField1 do
begin
  FillExpressions.Clear;
  with FillExpressions.AddExpression do
  begin
    SourceMemberName := 'CustomerPhoto';
    ControlMemberName := 'Bitmap';  // no error, means ControlMember exists
  end;
  with FillExpressions.AddExpression do
  begin
    SourceMemberName := 'CustomerID';  // just added this for testing
    ControlMemberName := 'Text';  // displays correct
  end;
end;
```

The Bitmap in `TListview` seems to be directly in it, whereas the 'Bitmap' of `TListbox` is in `ItemData` of the `TListboxitem` - could this be the issue?

Is there anything else to do to make the bitmap appear in `TListbox`, given that it's so automatic in `TListview`?